# Pandas column merging on condition

Tags: pandas

This is my pandas df:

```
Id  Protein A_Egg   B_Meat  C_Milk  Category
A   10        10      20       0    egg
B   20        10       0      10    milk
C   20        10      10      10    meat
D   25        20      10       0    egg
```

I wish to merge protein column with other column based on "Category"

My output is

```
Id  Protein_final
A      20         
B      30         
C      30
D      45
```

Ideally, I would like to show how I am approaching but, I am frankly clueless!!

EDIT: Also, How to handle is the category is blank or does meet one of the column (in that can final should be same as initial value in protein column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with some preprocessing with remove values in columns names before `_` and lowercase, last add to column:

```
arr = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[-1].lower()).lookup(df.index, df['Category'])

df['Protein'] += arr
print (df)
  Id  Protein  A_Egg  B_Meat  C_Milk Category
0  A       20     10      20       0      egg
1  B       30     10       0      10     milk
2  C       30     10      10      10     meat
3  D       45     20      10       0      egg
```

If need only 2 columns finally:

```
df = df[['Id','Protein']]
```

Comment: Thanks!
Just as edit: Also, How to handle is the category is blank or does meet one of the column (in that can final should be same as initial value in protein column).... in this case indexing with be of and will cause error....

Answer (score 1):

You can [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the dataframe, and filter for rows where category equals the variable column, and sum the final columns :

```
(
    df
     .melt(["Id", "Protein", "Category"])
     .assign(variable=lambda x: x.variable.str[2:].str.lower(),
             Protein_final=lambda x: x.Protein + x.value)
     .query("Category == variable")
     .filter(["Id", "Protein_final"])
)

    Id  Protein_final
  0 A   20
  3 D   45
  6 C   30
  9 B   30
```